npx create-turbo@latest yields error npm ERRNo workspaces found
package.json file is `
`{
  "name": "cohort",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}``

The log file is
0 verbose cli /home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/bin/node /home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js 1 info using npm@10.5.0 2 info using node@v18.20.2 3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms 4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms 5 timing config:load:file:/home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms 6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms 7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms 8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms 9 timing config:load:file:/home/rishabh/Music/Cohort/.npmrc Completed in 0ms 10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms 11 timing config:load:file:/home/rishabh/.npmrc Completed in 1ms 12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms 13 timing config:load:file:/home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms 14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms 15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms 16 timing config:load Completed in 12ms 17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms 18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms 19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms 20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms 21 verbose title npm exec create-turbo@latest 22 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create-turbo@latest" 23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms 24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms 25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/rishabh/.npm/_logs/2024-05-18T14_12_44_032Z- 26 verbose logfile /home/rishabh/.npm/_logs/2024-05-18T14_12_44_032Z-debug-0.log 27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms 29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms 30 timing npm:load Completed in 36ms 31 silly logfile done cleaning log files 32 timing command:exec Completed in 7ms 33 verbose stack Error: No workspaces found! 33 verbose stack     at getWorkspaces (/home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/workspaces/get-workspaces.js:48:11) 33 verbose stack     at async Exec.setWorkspaces (/home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/base-command.js:173:16) 33 verbose stack     at async Exec.execWorkspaces (/home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/exec.js:32:5) 33 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/home/rishabh/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5) 34 verbose cwd /home/rishabh/Music/Cohort 35 verbose Linux 5.4.0-174-generic 36 verbose node v18.20.2 37 verbose npm  v10.5.0 38 error No workspaces found! 39 verbose exit 1 40 timing npm Completed in 206ms 41 verbose code 1 42 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/rishabh/.npm/_logs/2024-05-18T14_12_44_032Z-debug-0.log
I can't run the command npx create-turbo@latest yields error npm ERR! No workspaces found!
node version is v18.20.2
npm version is 10.5.0
